# how do I create a formula for this

Tags: excel, excel-formula, matching

I would like to compare columns A, B, and C in sheet 1 to columns A, B, and C in sheet 2. If an exact match of all 3 columns in a row exists, I want to know the row number(s) (this could be multiple)

I have tried multiple formulas and cant get it to work. Mostly tried INDEX and MATCH formulas but i keep getting an error

```
=IF(ISNA(INDEX(B:B,MATCH(C2,A:A,0))),"",INDEX(B:B,MATCH(C2,A:A,0)))
```

sheet 1 and sheet 2 do not have the same number of rows. There could be multiple matches, but if the first 3 columns match each other, I want to know which ones they are.

Comment: Do you want the row numbers from sheet1 or sheet2?

Comment: Is the row numbers the final output or are you going to do something with that info in another formula?  If there is a different end result, it may be easier to get the end result than returning all the row numbers.

Comment: I would like the row numbers from sheet 2 thank you!

Comment: the row numbers are the final output. it will be used as a guide to tell us which rows of information we need to work on

Comment: Do you want the output in one cell or many?  If many, in one column or one row?

Comment: i would like the output in one cell.

Comment: For example, if sheet 1 A, B, and C match columns in sheet 2, A, B, and C, put the row number from sheet 2 into cell D in sheet 1

Comment: That is only possible with Office 365 and later OR vba.

Comment: OK...unfortunately i dont know vba - could you help me with the code? or would you happen to have any other suggestions as to how i can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would work:

```
=IF(AND(SHEET1!P17=SHEET2!T17,SHEET1!Q17=SHEET2!U17,SHEET1!R17=SHEET2!V17),SHEET2!ROW(),"")
```